# GSC URL inspection's limit to 2k URLs - what are the limit's rules?

Tags: google-search-console

A single GSC property limits its URL inspection to 2.000 URLs. In case there are more than 2.000 URLs - how GSC decides, which data to deliver? Are the 2.000 URLs those with the most traffic or random or ...?

Comment: The limit is only for Search Console URL Inspection API. It is a number of request per day that you can make, before reaching the limit. You can find more stuff here: https://developers.google.com/search/blog/2022/01/url-inspection-api

Comment: yes I mean this limit of 2000 daily queries

Answer (score 2):

I can inspect any URL on my site that I want, it doesn't have to be in the 2000 that Google lists. I can click on "URL inspection" in the left hand nav which takes me to the search bar and prompts me to type in any URL from my site.

[image]

Comment: I mean the usage limit of 2.000 queries a day, as stated here: https://developers.google.com/search/blog/2022/01/url-inspection-api

Comment: Google doesn't choose which ones to inspect, you do.